# jQuery Autocomplete - Multiple Selections

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to use jQuery with multiple selections from

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

The js works perfect however, when i change the place holder on 
**Line no 58** 
in the above url to a semi-colon, it does not work.

> this.value = terms.join( **"; "** );

Comment: Please, at least create a fiddle for it

Comment: Very sorry for that Alexander. I am new to Stack Overflow and indeed creating a fiddle is a good idea. Will keep that in mind hence forth. thanks for the advice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is set up to work with comma delimiters, and not semi-colon, so you also need to change line 19 from this:

```
return val.split( /,\s*/ );
```

to this:

```
return val.split( /;\s*/ );
```